# Нахождение общих символов двух строк

Tags: c++, строки, set

Была задача написать программу, которая находит все символы, встречающиеся в обеих переданных ей строках.
Реализовал через multiset, по идее все должно работать, однако проходит не все тесты и тест дающий ошибку придумать не могу.

Вот задача:
Напишите программу, которая находит все символы, встречающиеся в обеих переданных ей строках.

Входные данные
На вход программы подаются две символьные строки, каждая строка завершается символом "конец строки".

Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести все символы, которые встречаются в обеих строках, в порядке возрастания их ASCII-кодов. Если таких символов нет, нужно вывести слово 'NO'.
Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::string s1, s2;  std::cin >> s1 >> s2;
    std::multiset<char> a, b;
    std::multiset<char> intersection;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i)
    {
        a.insert(s1[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); ++i)
    {
        b.insert(s2[i]);
    }
    std::set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));
    if (intersection.size() != 0)
    {
        for (char i : intersection) 
        {
            std::cout << i;
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "NO";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: зачем тут multiset?

Comment: можете упростить себе жизнь с ```std::multiset<char> a(s1.begin(), s1.end()), b(s2.begin(), s2.end());```

Comment: Попробуйте обычный `set`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat обычный сет не подойдет, т.к. символы в ответе могут повторяться

Comment: @Limenal А точно могут? Можете задание скопипастить в вопрос?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat исправил. Однако я уже реализовывал через обычный сет и с выводом без повторов, в итоге проходило даже меньше тестов, чем сейчас

Answer (score 3):

Ну, я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    set<char> a(s.begin(),s.end());
    getline(cin,s);
    set<char> b(s.begin(),s.end());

    set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(),
                     b.begin(), b.end(),
                     ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " "));
    cout << "\n";
}
```

А, да, если ничего нет - то нужно же выводить `NO` - ну, думаю, тут вы допишете сами?..

Comment: еще бы стоило добавить проверку на пробелы

Comment: @SKIP А пробел что, не символ?... я как раз считал, что его тоже учитывать нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но все же, где в моей реализации косяк?

Comment: @Limenal Раз это сработало, то как минимум повторяющиеся символы в выводе были не нужны.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а есть ли различия между способами заполнения сета?

Comment: @Limenal Может у вас строки с пробелами? `>>` читает до первого пробела, а `getline` до конца строки.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Тоже об этом подумал, буду разбираться

Answer (score -1):

Используйте функции_члены std::string :

```
size_t pos = s1.find_first_of(s2);
while ( pos < s1.size()) {
    cout << s1[pos] << ' ';
    pos = s1.find_first_of(s2, pos + 1);
}
```

с помощью сета:

```
set<char> s(s1.begin(), s1.end());
for (char c : s2) {
    if (!s.emplace(c).second)
        cout << c << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы решить именно с помощью сета, потому что эту тему сейчас проходим в университете и задания дали по ней.